# Who pays to stop payment on a check lost in the mail?

Tags: check

I was expecting a check for work I performed as an independent contractor several weeks ago.  I emailed and was told the check was already mailed.  I was given a postage date and the check number.   Fwiw these are reasonable people with whom I've worked for many years.  I have no reason to suspect they are not being truthful.  Plus our mail delivery at home is unreliable.  I'm proceeding on the assumption that the check was lost in the mail.

It seems the best plan is to stop payment on the first check and have them mail another.  In this circumstance who is responsible for paying the bank fee for stopping payment?  If it matters, this is a tiny non-profit with no full time employees.  The director is part time and there are a dozen or so contractors like me.  The check amount was a few hundred dollars.

Comment: That's a whole different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The owner of the account the check would be drawn from is responsible if they want the check to be nullified, so they would pay to "stop payment". If the check is cashed, the money would come out of their account, so they would need to pay to stop that from happening.  There are way to try and recover money if the check is cashed fraudulently, but stopping payment is an easier way to be protected from that hassle. If they are willing to take that risk for a few hundred dollars, they are free to do that.

You could offer to allow then to reduce the amount of the new check if you think the fault lies with your local mail delivery, but if they want the check to keep from getting cashed fraudulently, they would need to pay for that protection.